# Belonging in the sense of belonging somewhere

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request

What is a Latin phrase to express the sense of belonging to a particular place?
How can  this be translated from English to Latin?

Comment: I added some tags to your question and then answered it, but it occurred to me right before posting the answer that I may have misunderstood your question. This might render the new tags and my answer irrelevant. Can you give an example or two of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the word adjective ***localis***.
It is not exactly the same as the English "local", but evidently related to it.

[Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=localis&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) translates it as "of or belonging to a place, local".
Some use examples are mentioned in the linked dictionary entry, including *adverbia localia* ("adverbs of place", Scaurus, *De Adverbio et Praepositione* 29.8) and *localiter* ("locally" or "by local inhabitants").

As always, the best translation depends on context, but the adjective *localis* is my best first guess for "belonging to some place".

Or did you perhaps mean phrases like "I was born here and I belong in this city"?
That would be a completely different story.

Answer (score 2):

You can say it in various ways to suit the context. For example, for 'belonging to Rome', you might choose from:

*Romanus natus sum* — I was born a Roman

*Civis Romanus sum* — I am a Roman citizen

*Incola sum Romae* — I am an inhabitant of/at Rome